# PCA: resultant matrix n-1 rows

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

I am using PCA in Python to reduce the dimensionality of the data I have. The current data has 768 rows and 10 columns.

I am using the following code to implement PCA:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import decomposition

demo_df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
pca = decomposition.PCA(n_components=4)

comps = pca.fit(demo_df).transform(demo_df)

np.savetxt('data_reduced.csv', comps, delimiter=',')
```

According to my understanding the resultant file should contain 768 rows and 4 columns (because n_components =4).

But the resultant data has n-1 rows i.e 767.

Why is one row missing from the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are right in your understanding. But check the shape of demo_df before passing it to PCA. It must be of length 767. PCA is not eliminating any sample from your data whatsoever.

The difference arises from the usage of `read_csv()`. Please have a look at the [documentation of pandas.read_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). It has a parameter `header` and its description is as following:

> header : int or list of ints, default ‘infer’
>
> Row number(s) to use as
>   the column names, and the start of the data. Default behavior is as if
>   set to 0 if no names passed, otherwise None. Explicitly pass header=0
>   to be able to replace existing names. The header can be a list of
>   integers that specify row locations for a multi-index on the columns
>   e.g. [0,1,3]. Intervening rows that are not specified will be skipped
>   (e.g. 2 in this example is skipped). Note that this parameter ignores
>   commented lines and empty lines if skip_blank_lines=True, so header=0
>   denotes the first line of data rather than the first line of the file.

It by defaults uses the **first line of file** as column headings if those headings are not provided explicitly by use of another parameter `names`.

So if you dont want to use the first line of your file as column headers, you should pass the `header = None` in read_csv() like this:

```
demo_df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header = None)
```